# Is it possible for a child process to get the PID of its siblings?

Tags: c, asynchronous, process, fork, exec

The child process is another C program run with `execlp`. The machine is Unix. I know the child process can access the process table with `execlp("ps", "ps", NULL)` but I can't figure out how it can determine its sibling.

Even though the processes are asynchronous, I know that the sibling process will be running.

Comment: Well, it's not even possible to `fork()` a "*child*" in [tag:c]. So let's assume you mean C with POSIX extensions. Then the answer is: **no**, this is *not* possible (without calling external tools or other platform-specific hacks). Could this be an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: There is no practical way to look this up (yeah, you _could_ in principle parse the output of `ps` but ugh).  You will need to communicate it, either from sibling to sibling or from parent to children. If you tell us why you need to know, we might be able to be more specific.

Comment: Would it be possible to getppid to get the parent's pid, then add 1 to it until we hit a valid pid that doesn't match the current child process's pid (getpid)? Is there a way to check if a pid is valid?

I know a more practical method is to have the child ask the parent for data on siblings, and have the parent pipe it back, but I'm curious.

Comment: @BryanTan You can check whether a pid corresponds to a live process with `kill(pid, 0)`, but imagine what happens if some unrelated process calls fork after your first child is created but before your second child is -- the next active pid won't belong to the sib you're looking for.  Also, in between `kill(pid, 0)` succeeding and you doing something with the information, the process at `pid` could exit _and be replaced with a different process_.

Comment: dude, you are trying to do something wrong. explain the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for a child process to get the PID of its siblings?

Without talking with the parent using sort of a protocol, this is not possible in a portable manner. On some systems it might not even be possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. I am attaching c code for this. Here I have taken 4 children and all are sharing their pid's.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_CHILDREN 4

/* Entry point for the child processes */
int child_main(int pipe_read_end) {
  pid_t my_pid = getpid();

  /* Read child pids from pipe */
  int child_pids[NUM_CHILDREN];
  unsigned int bytes_read = 0;
  while (bytes_read < sizeof(child_pids)) {
    ssize_t result = read(pipe_read_end, ((unsigned char *) child_pids) + bytes_read, sizeof(child_pids) - bytes_read);
    if (result < 0) {
      perror("error reading from pipe");
      return 1;
    } else if (result == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "unexpected end of file\n");
      return 1;
    } else {
      bytes_read += result;
    }
  }
  close(pipe_read_end);

  /* Do something useful with these child pids */
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
    printf("Child %d received sibling pid %d\n", my_pid, child_pids[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}

/* Entry point for the parent process. */
int main() {
  int child_pids[NUM_CHILDREN];
  int pipe_write_ends[NUM_CHILDREN];
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
    /* Create the pipe for child i */
    int pipefd[2];
    if (pipe(pipefd)) {
      perror("error creating pipe");
      return 1;
    }
    int pipe_read_end = pipefd[0];
    int pipe_write_end = pipefd[1];

    /* Fork child i */
    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid < 0) {
      perror("error forking");
      return 1;
    } else if (child_pid == 0) {
      printf("Child %d was forked\n", getpid());
      close(pipe_write_end);
      return child_main(pipe_read_end);
    } else {
      printf("Parent forked child %d\n", child_pid);
      close(pipe_read_end);
      pipe_write_ends[i] = pipe_write_end;
      child_pids[i] = child_pid;
    }
  }

  /* Send pids down the pipes for each child */
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
    unsigned int bytes_written = 0;
    while (bytes_written < sizeof(child_pids)) {
      ssize_t result = write(pipe_write_ends[i], ((unsigned char *) child_pids) + bytes_written, sizeof(child_pids) - bytes_written);
      if (result < 0) {
        perror("error writing to pipe");
        return 1;
      } else {
        bytes_written += result;
      }
    }
    close(pipe_write_ends[i]);
  }

  /* Wait for children to exit */
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
    if (waitpid(child_pids[i], 0, 0) < 0) {
      perror("error waiting for child");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  }
```